# How to keep session history?

Tags: oracle

I want to store to database users that access OBIEE, but i have problem:
If user exit from OBIEE then the session also removed, then how to keep the history of user that accessed the OBIEE?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to enable [Usage Tracking](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e10541/usage_track.htm#CEGFBCCE) in OBIEE.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `AFTER LOGON` trigger, which could insert a row in a table.

Comment: I already try after logon trigger, but can the after logon trigger apply in OBIEE?i want to keep information about user that access dashboard OBIEE but i just found the after logon on database.please help, thank so much

Comment: In that case I think Martin's suggestion is better.